# Include slide in Xaringan presentation if condition based on parameter is true

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I would like to include a slide only if a metadata parameter is true.
As an example if the rmarkdown::metadata$institute parameter is not NULL , include the slide showing institution's blurb.

Regards

Comment: I have solved this using the 'exclude:' class and an r expression with a ifelse() clause checking the contents of the YAML metadata parameter.  Hopefully someone else might find this useful or else I have a need issue :)